# Baby Rudin Exercise 11.15

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am working through the last chapter of baby Rudin I have a question about exercise 11.15. The question is

Let $\mathfrak{R}$ be the ring of all elementary subsets of $(0,1]$. If $0 < a \leq b \leq 1$ define
$$\phi([a,b]) = \phi([a,b)) = \phi((a,b]) = \phi((a,b)) = b-a $$
but define
$$\phi((0,b)) = \phi((0,b]) = 1+b $$
Show that this gives an additive set function $\phi$ on $\mathfrak{R}$, which is $\textbf{not regular}$ and which cannot be extended to a countably additive set function on a $\sigma$-ring.

I have been looking at solutions, such as [here](https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%2011.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), but I am having issues with the way it is proved that $\phi$ is not regular and I cannot think of an alternative proof. They say that $\phi$ is not regular because if we take a set like $(0, 0.5]$ then this cannot be approximated from below by a closed set because a closed set cant contain $0$ as the end point. But, isn't $(0, 0.5]$ closed in $(0,1]$? So it seems that this argument doesn't work. But, I also cannot think of an alternative argument to show that $\phi$ isn't regular.

Comment: Doesn't regularity require aproximating by **compact** subsets?

Comment: This is an old question, but I think $\phi$ is not regular if you approximate $(0, b]$ by $[1/n, b]$, which is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a screen shot of the page where Rudin proves that every regular set function  can be
extended to a countably additive set function.

I really don't understand where did the "compactness" assumption came from, but it is surely being used!

[image]

Moral:  I think that Definition (11.5) of regularity must be amended by requiring that the set $F$ mentioned there be compact, rather than just closed.  Otherwise Theorem (11.8) does not hold, and a counter example is precisely the one described by the OP!

Comment: Isn't the compactness from the fact that $F$ is an elementary set of $\mathbb{R}^p$? (bounded and closed implies compact)